# Postgresql 9.6 db connection our Oracle 11.2.0.4. db

Tags: postgresql, oracle, connectivity

I am trying to do a connection between tables/fields between our Postgresql database and an Oracle database.  When updates are made in one it needs to be as closely as possible updated in the other, back and forth.  I have tried to install the UnixODBC rpms (and others), but to no avail.  We are mired in thousands of dependencies that seem to go on forever!  Each time I seem to be close to possibly getting it to install it comes back needing even more RPMs.  There must be a solution out there that will allow me to accomplish this without all this headache.  Anything anyone can suggest would be appreciated.

Comment: The one solution to accomplish this without much effort is to hire someone who will do it for you.

Comment: Why don't you use a [foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a master-master-replication between oracle and PostgreSQL ? 
As mentioned in comments you should use foreign tables for. For example you can use the oracle_fdw extension to integrate your oracle tables into PostgreSQL.
You need to complie the extension with your oracle client libraries. The extension you can found here https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw